Extracting values from raster stack at x, y, and time point with terra in R
I want to match observations (at a point at a time) with raster data downloaded from a server. I understand I can use terra::extract() to get the value of a single point in a single raster layer using its coordinates, but how do I programmatically look up points in a stack by x, y, and time? Here's a reproducible example representing as far as I've gotten (includes code to download the raster data I'm using from the rerddap package):
library(terra)
library(rerddap)
set.seed(10)
latrange <- c(38, 40)
lonrange <- c(-37, -35) 

oisst <- "ncdcOisst2Agg_LonPM180"
oisst_time <- c("1982-01-02","1982-01-31")
oisst_fields <- "sst"
oisst_grid <- griddap(oisst, time=oisst_time, latitude = latrange, longitude = lonrange, fields=oisst_fields)

oisst_nc_file <- oisst_grid$summary$filename

oisst_rast <- rast(oisst_nc_file) # here's the data file 

points <- data.frame(x = runif(5, -37, -35), 
                     y = runif(5, 38, 40), 
                     date = c("1982-01-05","1982-01-10","1982-01-15","1982-01-20","1982-01-25"))

I want to programmatically add a column to the points dataframe with the sst value for each x, y, and date row. (This is a reproducible example but the real case involves many thousands of x, y, date combinations.) How do I do this?

You can do
lyr <- match(points$date, time(oisst_rast, "days"))
extract(oisst_rast, points[,1:2], layer=lyr)

#  ID         layer value
#1  1  sst_zlev=0_4 17.45
#2  2  sst_zlev=0_9 17.02
#3  3 sst_zlev=0_14 16.70
#4  4 sst_zlev=0_19 16.23
#5  5 sst_zlev=0_24 16.56



I would search for layers which are in data frame, subset the raster just for those layers and extract the values like:
library(terra)
library(rerddap)
set.seed(10)
latrange <- c(38, 40)
lonrange <- c(-37, -35) 

oisst <- "ncdcOisst2Agg_LonPM180"
oisst_time <- c("1982-01-02","1982-01-31")
oisst_fields <- "sst"
oisst_grid <- griddap(oisst, time=oisst_time, latitude = latrange, longitude = lonrange, fields=oisst_fields)

oisst_nc_file <- oisst_grid$summary$filename

oisst_rast <- rast(oisst_nc_file) # here's the data file 


The time of layers can be accessed with terra::time() function. Let's have a look on the class of the information there: it's POSIXct/lt, so, we will:

convert the date to POSIXct,
find the coresponding layers
substitute the raster stack

terra::time(oisst_rast) |>
  class()
#> [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"

points <- data.frame(x = runif(5, -37, -35), 
                     y = runif(5, 38, 40), 
                     date = c("1982-01-05","1982-01-10","1982-01-15","1982-01-20","1982-01-25"))


Sys.setenv(TZ="UTC")
a <- which(terra::time(oisst_rast) %in% as.POSIXct(paste(points$date, " 12:00:00")))
b <- terra::subset(oisst_rast, a)

terra::extract(b, points[, 1:2])
#>   ID sst_zlev=0_4 sst_zlev=0_9 sst_zlev=0_14 sst_zlev=0_19 sst_zlev=0_24
#> 1  1        17.45        17.19         16.81         16.81         16.71
#> 2  2        17.35        17.02         16.82         16.50         16.76
#> 3  3        17.30        16.95         16.70         16.50         16.81
#> 4  4        16.73        16.48         15.88         16.23         16.59
#> 5  5        17.15        16.89         16.71         16.40         16.56

In meantime I had to set up the locale Sys.setenv(TZ="UTC") not to fight with my local time zone which is 2 hours behind :)
Created on 2024-12-26 with reprex v2.1.1.9000
PS. This one seems to be somehow related: Read a .nc file and get variables at certain locations
PS2. Updated with your new input data.
Edit: a massage with dplyr to have everything in one column, as asked in comment. Please be aware it's much less effective, because it has to search for layer in stack in every row, the same to extract the values.
points <- points |>
  dplyr::rowwise() |>
  dplyr::mutate(sst = terra::extract(
    subset(oisst_rast, which(as.Date(time(oisst_rast)) == as.Date(date))),
    matrix(c(x, y), ncol = 2)
  )) 


points$sst <- apply(points$sst, 1, function(x) as.numeric(paste(x[!is.na(x)], collapse = ", ")));
points
#> # A tibble: 5 × 4
#> # Rowwise: 
#>       x     y date         sst
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>
#> 1 -36.0  38.5 1982-01-05  17.5
#> 2 -36.4  38.5 1982-01-10  17.0
#> 3 -36.1  38.5 1982-01-15  16.7
#> 4 -35.6  39.2 1982-01-20  16.2
#> 5 -36.8  38.9 1982-01-25  16.6


Some of the NAs arise from me choosing misleading lat/lon values in the reprex, which I've edited above. But why are there ten rows and five columns? Each set of coordinates should map on to one and only one SST value, because each is on a different date.

My mistake, already fixed it out. extract() function can take matrix/vect or 2-dim data.frame but not c("x", "y") obviously.

awesome, this is closer, but I think it's still giving SST at every possible combination of dates and coords. I can extract the diagonal from this output but is there a more efficient way to append a single column to points with the SST at a single x, y, time combination?

Extended the answer, but please be aware it might be less efficient for "many thousands of x, y, date combinations.", as it's subsetting the raster stack every row.
